# Why doesn't my number have commas when I've formatted it to

Tags: c#

Why doesn't my number have commas when I've formatted it to.

```
public string? DFreeSpace3 => $"{DFreeSpace:n0}";
```

[image]

Comment: Because you are formatting a string which doesn't care about the `n0` format?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] instead of screenshots. With that rep you should know that this is a minimum for a question like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot shows (not sure why you highlighted `DFreeSpace3` though!)

```
public string? DUsedSpace { get; set; }

public string? DUsedSpace3 => $"{DUsedSpace:n0}";
```

Unfortunately you cannot format strings using standard numeric formats like this. I assume you've done something similar for the highlighted `DFreeSpace3`

Try using `DUsedSpace2` instead which is a numeric type.

```
public string? DUsedSpace3 => $"{DUsedSpace1:n0}";
```